# running remote commands on kubernetes with gnu parallel?

Tags: kubernetes, gnu-parallel, kubectl

I want to run tcpdump against 500+ kubernetes pods, sampling for 30-120 seconds. `kubectl` against a single pod works great:

```
 $ kubectl exec -ti [POD NAME] timeout [SAMPLE TIME] tcpdump
 ...
 real tcpdump output in stdout!
```

I'd like to use `parallel`, which offers an easy way to dump out the results of this command. Prepending the above command with `parallel` doesn't work:

```
$ parallel kubectl exec -ti [POD NAME] timeout [SAMPLE TIME] tcpdump
Academic tradition requires you to cite works you base your article on.
When using programs that use GNU Parallel to process data for publication
please cite:

  O. Tange (2011): GNU Parallel - The Command-Line Power Tool,
  ;login: The USENIX Magazine, February 2011:42-47.

This helps funding further development; and it won't cost you a cent.
If you pay 10000 EUR you should feel free to use GNU Parallel without citing.

To silence the citation notice: run 'parallel --bibtex'.

parallel: Warning: Input is read from the terminal.
parallel: Warning: Only experts do this on purpose. Press CTRL-D to exit.
```

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: Run `parallel --bibtex` first to get rid of the message. Where are your pod names? In a file? If so `parallel --dry-run -a podnames.txt kubectl exec -ti {} ...`

Comment: Have you had a chance to walk through the tutorial? `man parallel_tutorial`

Comment: `-ti` was the problem! It was less an issue with parallel and more an issue of how I was invoking kubectl exec.

Comment: Update your question with how you resolved this issue..